# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not initialize a collection:

Tags: hibernate

This is the full stack trace. I checked all my tables and columns they are correctly mapped.
Does Hibernate automatically creates the join table ?Because i don't want that table ?I too won't have access to create a table in DB

```html
19:06:01,444 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3) SQL Error: 972, SQLState: 42000
19:06:01,444 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3) ORA-00972: identifier is too long

19:06:01,459 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3) org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not initialize a collection: [com.lv.rs.accessautomation.common.vo.QuoteUserInfoVO.quoteUserRoleVO#component[ssoId,quoteId]{quoteId=1, ssoId=LOPJS}]
19:06:01,460 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
19:06:01,460 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
19:06:01,460 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2173)
19:06:01,460 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:62)
19:06:01,460 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:627)
19:06:01,460 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:83)
19:06:01,461 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1863)
19:06:01,461 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:369)
19:06:01,461 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:111)
19:06:01,461 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:332)
19:06:01,461 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
19:06:01,461 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
19:06:01,462 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at com.lv.rs.accessautomation.common.vo.QuoteUserInfoVO.toString(QuoteUserInfoVO.java:85)
19:06:01,462 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
19:06:01,462 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
19:06:01,462 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:450)
19:06:01,462 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
19:06:01,462 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
19:06:01,462 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at com.lv.rs.accessautomation.business.service.impl.AccessServiceImpl.saveQuotesUser(AccessServiceImpl.java:138)
19:06:01,463 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at com.lv.rs.accessautomation.business.service.impl.AccessServiceImpl.saveUser(AccessServiceImpl.java:114)
19:06:01,463 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
19:06:01,463 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
19:06:01,463 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
19:06:01,463 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
19:06:01,463 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
19:06:01,463 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
19:06:01,464 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
19:06:01,464 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
19:06:01,464 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
19:06:01,464 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
19:06:01,464 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at $Proxy252.saveUser(Unknown Source)
19:06:01,464 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at com.lv.rs.accessautomation.view.controller.AutomationController.doActions(AutomationController.java:74)
19:06:01,465 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
19:06:01,465 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
19:06:01,465 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
19:06:01,465 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
19:06:01,465 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
19:06:01,465 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
19:06:01,466 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
19:06:01,466 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
19:06:01,466 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
19:06:01,466 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
19:06:01,466 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
19:06:01,466 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
19:06:01,467 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
19:06:01,467 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
19:06:01,467 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
19:06:01,467 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
19:06:01,467 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
19:06:01,467 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
19:06:01,468 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
19:06:01,468 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
19:06:01,468 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
19:06:01,468 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
19:06:01,468 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:505)
19:06:01,468 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:445)
19:06:01,469 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
19:06:01,469 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
19:06:01,469 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3) Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long
19:06:01,469 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3) 
19:06:01,469 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
19:06:01,469 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
19:06:01,469 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
19:06:01,469 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
19:06:01,470 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
19:06:01,470 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
19:06:01,470 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
19:06:01,470 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:862)
19:06:01,470 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1153)
19:06:01,470 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1275)
19:06:01,470 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
19:06:01,471 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3620)
19:06:01,471 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
19:06:01,471 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
19:06:01,471 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
19:06:01,471 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
19:06:01,471 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
19:06:01,472 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2166)
```

Iam making a many to may relation between two tables, but i don't want any fields to be generated like primary key or have a join table. But if i run my code ti get the belwo exception.

```
19:06:01,444 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3) SQL Error: 972, SQLState: 42000
19:06:01,444 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3) ORA-00972: identifier is too long

19:06:01,459 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8016-3) org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not initialize a collection:
```

```js
/**
 * 
 */


import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

   
@Entity
@Table(name="QT_USER_ROLE")
public class QuoteUserRoleVO implements Serializable{
 
 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @Id
 @Column(name = "SSO_ID")
 private String ssoId;
 @Id
 @Column(name = "QUOTE_TYPE_ID")
 private int quoteId;
 @Id
 @Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
 private int roleId;
 @Column(name = "ADMINISTRATOR_FLG")
 private String adminFlg;
 @Column(name = "UNDERWRITER_FLG")
 private String underWriterFlg;
 
 @ManyToMany(mappedBy="quoteUserRoleVO")
 private Set<QuoteUserInfoVO> quoteUserInfoVO = new HashSet<QuoteUserInfoVO>();
 
 public String getSsoId() {
  return ssoId;
 }
 public void setSsoId(String ssoId) {
  this.ssoId = ssoId;
 }
 public int getQuoteId() {
  return quoteId;
 }
 public void setQuoteId(int quoteId) {
  this.quoteId = quoteId;
 }
 public int getRoleId() {
  return roleId;
 }
 public void setRoleId(int roleId) {
  this.roleId = roleId;
 }
 public String getAdminFlg() {
  return adminFlg;
 }
 public void setAdminFlg(String adminFlg) {
  this.adminFlg = adminFlg;
 }
 public String getUnderWriterFlg() {
  return underWriterFlg;
 }
 public void setUnderWriterFlg(String underWriterFlg) {
  this.underWriterFlg = underWriterFlg;
 }
 public Set<QuoteUserInfoVO> getQuoteUserInfoVO() {
  return quoteUserInfoVO;
 }
 public void setQuoteUserInfoVO(Set<QuoteUserInfoVO> quoteUserInfoVO) {
  this.quoteUserInfoVO = quoteUserInfoVO;
 }
 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "QuoteUserRoleVO [ssoId=" + ssoId + ", quoteId=" + quoteId
    + ", roleId=" + roleId + ", adminFlg=" + adminFlg
    + ", underWriterFlg=" + underWriterFlg + "]";
 }
 
 

}
```

```html
/**
 * 
 */


import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="QT_USER_INFORMATION")
public class QuoteUserInfoVO implements Serializable{
 
 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
 @Id
 @Column(name = "SSO_ID")
 private String ssoId;
 @Id
 @Column(name = "QUOTE_TYPE_ID")
 private int quoteId;
 @Column(name = "FORENAME_TXT")
 private String forename;
 @Column(name = "SURNAME_TXT")
 private String surname;
 @Column(name = "ACTIVE_FLG")
 private String activeFlag;
 
 @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
 private Set<QuoteUserRoleVO> quoteUserRoleVO = new HashSet<QuoteUserRoleVO>();
 
 public String getSsoId() {
  return ssoId;
 }
 public void setSsoId(String ssoId) {
  this.ssoId = ssoId;
 }
 public int getQuoteId() {
  return quoteId;
 }
 public void setQuoteId(int quoteId) {
  this.quoteId = quoteId;
 }
 public String getForename() {
  return forename;
 }
 public void setForename(String forename) {
  this.forename = forename;
 }
 public String getSurname() {
  return surname;
 }
 public void setSurname(String surname) {
  this.surname = surname;
 }
 public String getActiveFlag() {
  return activeFlag;
 }
 public void setActiveFlag(String activeFlag) {
  this.activeFlag = activeFlag;
 }
 public Set<QuoteUserRoleVO> getQuoteUserRoleVO() {
  return quoteUserRoleVO;
 }
 public void setQuoteUserRoleVO(Set<QuoteUserRoleVO> quoteUserRoleVO) {
  this.quoteUserRoleVO = quoteUserRoleVO;
 }
 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "QuoteUserInfoVO [ssoId=" + ssoId + ", quoteId=" + quoteId
    + ", forename=" + forename + ", surname=" + surname
    + ", activeFlag=" + activeFlag + ", quoteUserRoleVO="
    + quoteUserRoleVO + "]";
 }
 
 

}
```

Comment: check your column names /table names . that is where the error is coming from , I guess

Comment: Post the complete stack trace. A ManyToMany without a join table is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The root issue here seems to be "ORA-00972: identifier is too long error". Since you are trying to access the oracle db using the hibernate orm, the implicit sql generated by hibernate could be having identifiers with length > 30. Since you have @ManyToMany association for certain fields in the above domain objects, the sql generated for the join could be having a larger length identifier.

To fix the issue, you can try using smaller identifier names as the join usually creates identifiers with `<TABLE1_NAME>_<FIELD1_NAME>_<TABLE2_NAME>_<FIELD2_NAME>`, which is clearly exceeding the length of 30 with the above domain entities.

Another way to fix the issue is to use CustomerNamingStrategy for hibernate by implementing the NamingStrategy Interface in hibernate (javadocs : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/class-use/NamingStrategy.html).

For Oracle specific custom naming strategy, check out the sample code at https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-naming-strategy-for-oracle/downloads/list.

Hope this helps!!